# Математическое уравнение Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

По данным действительными числами х, у вычислить f(x, 2y + 7) -7 f(4y, x), где:[image]

Мой неверный код:

```
import math 
x = int(input("Введите x: "))
y = int(input("Введите y: "))


def f(a,b):
    while 1 < abs(round(b)):
        return 2.5*math.sin(a+b)
    

answer = f(x, 2*y + 7) - f(4*y, x)
print(f"Результат: {answer:.3f}")
```

Comment: Так а семерка где перед второй функцией?

Comment: Вам известно что означает сигма в формуле? Это сумма значений от и до. Этого у вас совсем нет. Ну и семёрка пропущена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math

x = int(input("Введите x: "))
y = int(input("Введите y: "))

def f(a, b, i):
    return 2.5 * math.sin(a * i + b)

i = 1
s = 0
while i <= abs(round(y)):
    s += f(x, 2 * y + 7, i) - 7 * f(4*y, x, i)
    i += 1

print(s)
```